# PJSIP porting to Windows-10 Universal Application

Tags: windows-runtime, windows-10, voip, pjsip

I am able to port PJSIP library to Universal Windows 10.Then I have created universal DLL which has reference of the ported PJSIP libraries. I am loading this DLL using Universal application.
The application is working fine. But the issue is only waveInOpen() API. It is getting failed. But waveOutWrite() is successful. 
I have not done any code change in PJSIP library code.
Need some suggestion.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The error is it is returning 1. That is "unhandled external error"

Comment: You'll need to debug with source to find out.

Comment: Thanks. I debugged it. This is the Windows API so nothing to debug. The same libraries works as it is with non-Universal applications

Comment: Where did you obtain the PJSIP library? If it's open source, you'll need to debug into it to see what's failing. I suspect it's calling an API that isn't OK in a UWP app. But, without more information here, it's difficult to say what the problem is.

Comment: What is your Status, I am having a similar problem.